# How to cross-reference/link a chapter from an Office.js add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

Word has a "[cross-reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-cross-reference-300b208c-e45a-487a-880b-a02767d9774b)" feature that allows referencing other parts of the document.

I'd like to use that feature in Office.js to add a sentence like "More information can be found in Chapter 1: Introduction". It's important that the reference is a link to the actual chapter.

Apparently the new WordAPI 1.4 adds bookmark functionality. Sadly, this is not very well documented, but I assumed this could be used to create a bookmark somewhere in the document and then link to it later:

```
targetRange.insertBookmark("_test")
```

This seems to work, but how do I reference the bookmark? I tried using the `Word.Range.hyperlink` property:

```
referenceRange.hyperlink = "#_test"
await context.sync()
```

But the context.sync() call fails with an exception:

```
 {
    "name": "RichApi.Error",
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "traceMessages": [],
    "innerError": null,
    "debugInfo": {
        "code": "GeneralException",
        "message": "GeneralException",
        "errorLocation": "Range.hyperlink",
        "statement": "range.hyperlink = ...;",
        "surroundingStatements": [
            "...",
            "// Instantiate {body}",
            "var range = body.getRange();",
            "// Instantiate {range}",
            "// >>>>>",
            "range.hyperlink = ...;",
            "// <<<<<",
            "..."
        ],
    },
    "httpStatusCode": 500
}
```

Is there a special format to set a hyperlink? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code that you actually tested (the exception seems to list different code than the code in your description. FWIW I tried the code more or less as described in the exception and it worked OK here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code. I added "await context.sync()" after "targetRange.insertBookmark("_test")". It works. Could you please try my code?
[image]